# SoundManager 2 - JQuery Como puedo pasar a la cancion siguiente o anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

estoy usando un plugin de JQuery llamado [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc) Y estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica vaya.
Basicamente que haga **pause/play** que lo hace bien y que pase a la **siguiente** cancion , o que **retroceda** a la anterior.

Pues bien, por lo visto este plugin no tiene una funcion `.next()` ni una funcion `.previous()`.

No se si alguien sabe como hacer eso: **cancion siguiente** y **cancion anterior**

```
< script >
    //REPRODUCTOR MUSICA

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mySound = null;

        //ejepmlo interesante para otra cosa
        // soundManager.play('mySound2');

        soundManager.setup({
            //la url es donde esta el pluging (dir:/swf/)
            url: './soundmanagerv297a-20170601/swf/',
            onready: function() {
                mySound = soundManager.createSound({
                    id: ['musica_1', 'musica_2'],
                    url: ['./musica/Music_Mix_2018.mp3', './musica/Virtual_Riot_Energy_Drink.mp3']
                });
                mySound.play();
            },
            ontimeout: function() {
                // Hrmm, SM2 could not start. Missing SWF? Flash blocked? Show an error, etc.?
            }
        });

        $("#btn_anterior").click(function() {
           // mySound.next(-1); NO FUNCIONA
        });
        $("#btn_reanudar").click(function() {
            $("#btn_parar").show();
            mySound.resume();
            $("#btn_reanudar").hide();

        });
        $("#btn_parar").click(function() {

            $("#btn_parar").hide();
            mySound.pause();
            $("#btn_reanudar").show();
        });
        $("#btn_siguiente").click(function() {
           // mySound.next(); NO FUNCIONA
        });

    });

< /script>
```